# xpathSApply() returning line(), h3lp please

Tags: r

Hi I can't get this function working....

On the webpage :

http://www.meetup.com/stats-prog-dc/members/?sort=chapter_member.atime&desc=1&offset=3

there are links with  memName  class, for instance :

```
<a href="http://www.meetup.com/stats-prog-dc/members/94995702/" class="memName">Asuri</a>
```

In R, I type the following commands :

```
>web <- getURL("http://www.meetup.com/stats-prog-dc/members/?sort=chapter_member.atime&desc=1&offset=3", ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
>webhtml <- htmlTreeParse(web,error=function( ...){},useInternalNodes=TRUE,encoding="UTF-8",trim=TRUE)
>vNames <- xpathSApply(webhtml,'//*[@class="memName "]', xmlValue)
>vNames
```

The problem is that vNames returns "list()" instead of a list containing "Asuri" and all the other names. Please why is it not working this is killing me, help in R is so unclear.

Why does xpathSApply return an error if I don't put arguments in htmlTreeParse(web) ? 
What is the argument xmlValue in xpathSApply it's not even mentionned its help page !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added a space to the attribute name. Use

```
xpathSApply(webhtml,'//*[@class="memName"]', xmlValue)

 [1] "James Conkling"     "Mary Clare Peate"   "Mike Hodel"        
 [4] "Harlan Harris"      "kenny"              "Alex McKenzie"     
 [7] "KJ"                 "shaema talib"       "Brian Sacash"      
[10] "fbohorqu"           "Peter"              "Steve Swartz"      
[13] "Russell"            "J. Kader Hyer"      "T Woo"             
[16] "Rajavel Sethupathi" "Clarence Dillon"    "Patrick Wheatley"  
[19] "Anna Shaver"        "anupam"
```

instead.

`xmlValue` gives you the value of a particular node. `?xmlValue` will give you the help page. `xpathSApply` has a parameter `fun` which is for the function to apply to each node.
You can use for example `xmlAttrs` if you want the attributes of a particular node:

```
> xpathSApply(webhtml,'//*[@class="memName"]',xmlAttrs)
      [,1]                                                   
href  "http://www.meetup.com/stats-prog-dc/members/37625662/"
class "memName"                                              
      [,2]                                                   
href  "http://www.meetup.com/stats-prog-dc/members/94691152/"
class "memName"                                              
      [,3]                                                   
href  "http://www.meetup.com/stats-prog-dc/members/91583452/"
class "memName"
```

Comment: Nice thank's, now I understand more, sorry I'm new with R and scripting